# How Many Congruent Prisms Can Fit on a Common Segment

Tags: geometry, volume

The question is as follows:

> A triangular prism of cheese is measured and found to be 2.0 inches tall. The edges of its base are 9.0, 9.0, and 4.0 inches long. Several congruent prisms are to be arranged around a common 2.0-inch segment, as shown below. How many prisms can be accommodated? What is their total volume?
>
> [image]

I don't know where to start for this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would the problem be different expressed with the same numerical values in centimeters :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need the angle $\theta$ between the sides $9$ inches long

For cosine law we have

$4^2=9^2+9^2-2\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot \cos \theta$

$\cos\theta=\frac{73}{81}\to \theta\approx 25.67°$

$360/25.67\approx 14$

We can have $14$ slices maximum

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to confirm my answer with your's :)